# Replicating portfolio of an option and to find inital price

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, arbitrage, replication, equivalent-measure

I am very new to financial math so I am not sure how to do with this question. A friend sent me this question to practice but I am unsure how to begin. I read about call option . Can that be used for any option? Any help would be appreciated.

> Consider the following discrete time one-period market model. The savings
> account is at \$1 at time 0  and \$$\beta$ at time 1. The stock price is given by $S_0 = 1$
> and $S_1 = \xi$ where $\xi$ is a random variable taking two possible values $u$ and $d$,
> each with positive probability. Moreover, assume that $0 < d < \beta < u$.
> **Find, with proof, the risk-neutral measure of this model. Does this model have arbitrage opportunities?**

Comment: Since you are new to financial maths and your question is about binomial tree model, perhaps you can read [Steven Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for I: The Binomial Asset Pricing Model](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387401003)? The book's Chapter 1 covers your question. I learn binomial tree model from this book. If you would like to proceed to models in continuous time (such as Black-Scholes model, a famous option pricing model), you can read volume 2.

Comment: thanks for the comment!! i will read through this.